How I can calculate the average of timestamps in a mm:ss.ms format?
At the table mentioned upon: How I can take the timediff between timestamps that are in mm:ss.m format in google sheets?
I managed to calculate the Delta but now I want to calculate the Average of times as well.
Based on the answer I tried this formula:
=average(value("0:" & B2:B9))

But got the following output.
#VALUE!

How I can get the average values of this as well?
The values of column B are timestamps in the format of mm:ss.ms:
07:38.661
07:48.565
07:57.079
07:39.527
07:53.594
07:52.561
07:48.409
07:58.154



calculate the Average of times

Assuming that the times are text strings in column B2:B, you can get the "average time" like this:
=average(filter(value("0:" & B2:B), len(B2:B)))

In the event the values in column B2:B are numeric time or duration values, you can just use average(), like this:
=average(B2:B)

The result will be a dateserial value. You can format it through Format > Number > Custom number format > mm:ss.000.
See Working with date and time values in Google Sheets.

The column B is a number with format ([mm]:ss.000)

Tried to format then use the average function and not I got #DIV/0

avarage maybe mean average ?? It seem like a typo 2 me.

In my case was =average(filter(value("0:" & B2:B9), len(B2:B9)))'
